# SQL cannot add columns to query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have the following query (PostgreSQL 9.5.19):

```
with userlist as (
  select a.ips, 
         array_agg(t.super_user_id) as super_users
  from tmp_table_1 t
    left join unnest(t.ips) as a(ips) on true
  group by a.ips
), shared_users as (
  select u.ips,
         array(select distinct ul.uid
               from userlist u2, unnest(u2.super_users) as ul(uid)
               where u.super_users && u2.super_users
               order by ul.uid) as super_users
  from userlist u
)
select s.super_users, array_agg(distinct s.ips) as ips, 
    (select sum(msg_count) from tmp_table_1 where super_user_id in s.super_users) as sum_msg_count
from shared_users s
group by s.super_users;
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "s"
> LINE 38: ...sg_count) from tmp_table_1 where super_user_id in s.super_us...
>                                                               ^
> ```

It seems like I cannot access `s.super_users` from within the subquery.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Here is a full example:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/geB9V6TdHEkF2mSqpd2b4g/1

Maybe I am not approaching this correctly?

**Question**

How can I add the additional columns (`sum_msg_count`, `sum_user_count`, `max_last_date` and `pubs`) to the result set?

**Desired result**

```
|super_users                      |  ips                                                        |sum_msg_count| sum_user_count  |   max_last_date                | pubs                        |
|---------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------|-------------|-----------------|--------------------------------|-----------------------------|
|{522460771,522460772,522460773}  |  {94.134.88.115,94.134.88.124,94.134.88.125,94.134.88.136}  | 30          |         9       |  "2018-06-30 21:29:48.664000"  |  {ad2,googlecooler,ads,ad1} |
|{522460774,522460775}            |  {127.0.0.1,5.5.5.5}                                        | 20          |         6       |  "2018-06-30 21:29:48.664000"  |  {googlecooler,ad3,ad1}     |
|{522460776}                      |  {8.8.8.8}                                                  | 10          |         3       |  "2018-06-30 21:29:48.664000"  |  {googlecooler,ads}         |
```

Comment: `where super_user_id in s.super_users` IN requires a list like `where super_user_id in (select super_user_id from some_table)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ANY`, not `IN` to [search in an array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING)

```
...where super_user_id = ANY (s.super_users)
```

Comment: thank you that works. Now I just need to work out how to add the `pubs` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
with userlist as (
  select a.ips, array_agg(t.super_user_id) as super_users
  from tmp_table_1 t
    left join unnest(t.ips) as a(ips) on true
  group by a.ips
),
shared_users as (
  select u.ips,
         array(select distinct ul.uid
               from userlist u2, unnest(u2.super_users) as ul(uid)
               where u.super_users && u2.super_users
               order by ul.uid) as super_users
  from userlist u
) --select * from shared_users
select s.super_users, array_agg(distinct s.ips) as ips, 
(select sum(msg_count) from tmp_table_1 where super_user_id = any(s.super_users)) as sum_msg_count,
(select sum(user_count) from tmp_table_1 where super_user_id = any(s.super_users)) as sum_user_count,
(select max(last_date) from tmp_table_1 where super_user_id = any(s.super_users)) as max_last_date,
(select array_agg(pubs) from (select a.pubs, array_agg(t.super_user_id) as super_users
    from tmp_table_1 t 
  left join unnest(t.pubs) as a(pubs) on true
  and t.super_user_id = any(s.super_users)
  where a.pubs is not null
  group by a.pubs) as pubsAlias) as pubs  
from shared_users s
group by s.super_users;
```